# Setting S3 Bucket Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a website where users can upload files directly to amazon s3. I temporarily sign a url w/ my secret key that grants the user temporary PUT access to my site. This is possible through the CORS configuration.

Now, once the files are up there I want no one to read them but me. The current bucket policy I have disallows everyone from reading objects *including* me, the admin. Which is not good. What bucket policy will help me here?

Here is my working CORS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://url.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**UPDATE**: Works with this policy:

```
 {
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                             "NotPrincipal": {
                                "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob"
                             }
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok we created an IAM user with full permission to S3, we use this user to sign the temporary policies to allow the upload.  The User policy for the user is (You could further restrict this user to allow access to only one bucket, or even further to allow the user only put permissions on the bucket):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

We then create a temporary policy to allow an upload into our useruploads bucket

```
{ "expiration": "2013-11-20T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "useruploadtest"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "russ"], 
    {"acl": "public-read"}, 
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
  ]
}
```

We then sign the base64 encoded policy with our secret key (this code below is a sample of creating the signature with cryptojs never put your secret key in client side code)

```
  <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js">    </script>
  <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1LTEyLTAxVDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLA0KICAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJ1c2VydXBsb2FkdGVzdCJ9LA0KICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJGtleSIsICJydXNzIl0sIA0KICAgIHsiYWNsIjogInB1YmxpYy1yZWFkIn0sIA0KICAgIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9zdWNjZXNzZnVsX3VwbG9hZC5odG1sIn0sDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlLyJdLA0KICBdDQp9", "YourSecretKeyHere");
    var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    console.log(base64);
  </script>
```

Then you can use the signed policy to allow a temporary upload

```
<form action="http://useruploadtest.s3.amazonaws.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/successful_upload.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AKIAJM3U7AMGF6J6YYWQ" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1LTEyLTAxVDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLA0KICAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJ1c2VydXBsb2FkdGVzdCJ9LA0KICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJGtleSIsICJydXNzIl0sIA0KICAgIHsiYWNsIjogInB1YmxpYy1yZWFkIn0sIA0KICAgIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9zdWNjZXNzZnVsX3VwbG9hZC5odG1sIn0sDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlLyJdLA0KICBdDQp9" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Signature" value="Db4K65tz/WJtjAUUCWRn5MXdAJ4=" />


    Key to upload: <input type="input" name="key" value="test.jpg" /><br />
    Content-Type: <input type="input" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    File: <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
```

So long as the bucket in our case "useruploadtest" allows read access from another IAM user which we use in our application to read the files and process them it all works.

Hope this helps

Comment: I created an additional user as you said, and attached the user policy you have provided. Still getting a 403 on upload. I'm signing url's with the new access keys as well. When I remove the policy I can then upload (weird...). Do I need to additionally specify a bucket policy and specify proper grantees?

Comment: Figuring out how Grantees relate to IAM users, and how IAM user policies work with bucket policies, and how to specify proper bucket policies is a PITA

Comment: lol, yeah it can be..

There may be an issue with the ARN in my post, try the bucketname without the / (i think that only works for folders in the bucket soz), so in my example it would be arn:aws:s3:::useruploads*

Comment: ahh crap my post is wrong mate, Im just checking something now and ill update it

Comment: I think you need to include the action "Action":"s3:PutObjectAcl" as well. But this still doesn't stop the bucket from being read by everyone publicly.

Comment: yeah i didn't include the correct action, and i didn't include how you need to generate the temp policy and sign it.

Comment: I got it. This line did it: "Effect": "Deny",
"NotPrincipal": {
    "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob"
}

Comment: Hope the updated post helps somewhat, its good you got it in the end anyway.  good luck